# When i resize my GUI panel with Dynamic elements in it.. those elements are scrambled

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

Java: When i resize my GUI panel with Dynamic elements in it.. those elements are scrambled

I have this Jpanel opened. When i resize this window..
Some dynamic elements are scramled in a 2nd jpanel.. why is this?

It is a very long text of code and i dont know what i have to post.. but i can tell you this:

- 1: i have this GUI jPAnel named jpBarDetails
- 2: a public void that is generating dynamic components for within this jPAnel
- 3: I start with 2 dropdown menu's for selecting method of payment..
  when this method    is selected, the panel panelPayDetails is loaded.

So.. when i resize the window.. all items within the dynamic panel panelPayDetails are scrambled when i resize the window by only 5 pixels or so

```
public void initAfrekenenDisplay() {
          jpBarDetails.removeAll();
               rekeningContant.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            panelPayDetails.setBounds(245, 10, 360, 275);
                            panelPayDetails.setSize(360, 275);
                            panelPayDetails.setBackground(payDetailColor);
                            panelPayDetails.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
                            jpBarDetails.add(panelPayDetails);

                            JLabel lblLidNummerResult = new JLabel("Lidnummer:");
                            lblLidNummerResult.setBounds(10, 175, 200, 20);
                            lblLidNummerResult.setFont(Applicatie.FONT_12_BOLD);
                            panelPayDetails.add(lblLidNummerResult);

                            final JTextField jtfLidNummerResult = new JTextField();
                            jtfLidNummerResult.setBounds(180, 175, 130, 20);
                            jtfLidNummerResult.enable(false);
                            jtfLidNummerResult.setBackground(verLightGray);
                            panelPayDetails.add(jtfLidNummerResult);

                            JLabel lblLidNaamResult = new JLabel("Naam:");
                            lblLidNaamResult.setBounds(10, 197, 200, 20);
                            lblLidNaamResult.setFont(Applicatie.FONT_12_BOLD);
                            panelPayDetails.add(lblLidNaamResult);

                            final JTextField jtfLidNaamResult = new JTextField();
                            jtfLidNaamResult.setBounds(180, 197, 130, 20);
                            jtfLidNaamResult.enable(false);
                            jtfLidNaamResult.setBackground(verLightGray);
                            panelPayDetails.add(jtfLidNaamResult);

                            JLabel lblLidGeboortedatumResult = new                               JLabel("Geboortedatum:");
                            lblLidGeboortedatumResult.setBounds(10, 220, 200, 20);
                            lblLidGeboortedatumResult.setFont(Applicatie.FONT_12_BOLD);
                            panelPayDetails.add(lblLidGeboortedatumResult);
                }
            });
   }
```

Comment: It might be easier to help if we could see a minimal example of failing code. Where "might" == "would".

Comment: I'll read your mind in 1/2 the time it takes @MarounMaroun, but I cost a lot more ;-)  Seriously though, you need to post an `SSCCE` that demostrates your problem.

Comment: if you put some code will be great..

Comment: Ok.. i'll add some code

Comment: Don't use a null layout!!! Don't use the setBounds() method to position/size a component, that is the job of the layout manager. If you use a proper layout manager the realignment/resizing of components will happen automatically. Also the code you post is NOT a `SSCCE`, so we can't give any specific advice. Change your code to use layout managers and then post a SSCCE if you still have problems.

Comment: never-ever do any manual sizing/locating: that's the exclusive task of a suitable LayoutManager

Comment: i add dynamic componenets into the layout manager.. i have a loop to create multiple buttons

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a look at layout management for Java.

You can either have components absolutely positioned, or have layouts within layouts which compensate for when the windows is resized.

Additionally, you should consider that your GUI will also be affected by the settings of the operating system (e.g. class look vs windows 7), and the actual OS + Window Manager.

You should not rely that someone that looks OK on your system will appear like that in another OS.

Some useful links:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/howLayoutWorks.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html
- [Programming a GUI with resizable components using Java.swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280667/programming-a-gui-with-resizable-components-using-java-swing)
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html