# Dynamically resizable tables on a GUI

Tags: java, swing, resize, jtable, jgoodies

I have a GUI with a few `JTextField`s and `JTable`s, and I would like to get the possibility to dynamically re-size the tables after running the application, so the user can increase the size of the tables by clicking on the border and dragging it.

I am considering [this option](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280667/programming-a-gui-with-resizable-components-using-java-swing) post, but not sure if that´s what I need.

`JTable`s are combined with table scrollers, and the GUI uses a `JPanel` with `JGoodiesFormLayout`, since it makes very easy to work with rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`JSplitPanes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) to divide the GUI where you want to allow the user to specify the component limits.